# How to use std::num_get<> in self-defined istream?

Tags: c++

I wrote a istream for bits. When I wanted to implement formatted input, I copied the implementation of `_Common_extract_with_num_get` and `istreambuf_iterator` from msvc for experiment, here is part of relevant code:

```
using numget = std::num_get<char, ibstreambuf_iterator<char>>;
...

template <class _Ty>    
basic_ibstream& _Common_extract_with_num_get(_Ty& _Val) { // formatted extract with num_get     
    bios::iostate _Err = bios::goodbit;     
    const sentry _Ok(*this);        
    if (_Ok)    
        _STD use_facet<numget>(this->getloc()).get(*this, {}, *this, _Err, _Val);       
    _Base::setstate(_Err);      
    return *this;   
}
```

but when _Ty is bool, a breakpoint is triggered.

```
(*Exception thrown at 0x79324630 (msvcp140d.dll) in xstl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.*)
```

when _Ty is not bool, complier shows

```
'_InIt std::num_get<char,_InIt>::get(_InIt,_InIt,std::ios_base &,std::ios_base::iostate &,bool &) const': 
   cannot convert argument 5 from '_Ty' to 'bool &'
```

Comment: Please format your posting so it is readable.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. In China, you even cannot load entire webpage, so it's hard to edit question. I've tried my best

Comment: As an aside, there is a new IO library, growing in popularity, called `format`. I did not spend enough time with it yet to fully endorse it, but it cannot really be worse than iostream. It is said to be significantly faster, though, which if nothing else is an upside.